# 2d or 3d array in Google App Engine persistence?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, list, jdo

Using JDO and Persistence, I'm able to successfully store an ArrayList field and retrieve it from a class later. Unfortunately, arrays like `myobject[][][]` are not supported, as stated in documentation. I tried `ArrayList<ArrayList<myobject>>`, but this gives many errors, and careful reading of the [documentation](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html#Collections) would seem to suggest this may not be possible.

Is it possible to persist an array of two or more dimensions? If so, what is the most correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you want multiple dimensions and don't intend to query on any of the values therein, use Java serialization and store the result as a blob.

Comment: Exactly, and in fact you can't query over any of the internal values of such an array anyway (with JDOQL).

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you give an example? Unfortunately it seems a Text or Blob will not persist in the class. I'm not using JDOQL, just a persisting G.A.E. class.

Comment: You mean @Persistent(serialized="true")? That doesn't seem to work, can you link/post an example?